# Parse index.html with Nokogiri and assign a.link with the following text

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Please help me to figure out how to properly assign Build name with date and then sort out all link in ascending order by upload date.

Example of Index.html looks as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head><title>Index of localhost/BUILD</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of localhost/BUILD</h1>
<pre>Name             Last modified      Size</pre><hr/>
<pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="BUILD.10.tar">BUILD.10.tar</a>   27-Sep-2017 15:46  250 bytes
<a href="BUILD.13.tar">BUILD.13.tar</a>   28-Sep-2017 12:14  254 bytes
<a href="BUILD.15.tar">BUILD.15.tar</a>   29-Sep-2017 08:56  257 bytes
<a href="BUILD.16.tar">BUILD.16.tar</a>   29-Sep-2017 08:56  258 bytes
<a href="BUILD.17.tar">BUILD.17.tar</a>   29-Sep-2017 08:56  256 bytes
<a href="BUILD.9.tar">BUILD.9.tar</a>    27-Sep-2017 15:44  247 bytes
</pre>
<hr/><address style="font-size:small;">Artifactory/5.2.1 Server</address></body></html>
```

Currently my script looks as the following:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

  build_url = "/home/index.html"
  index_html = open(build_url).read
  index_dom = Nokogiri::HTML.parse index_html

  builds =[]
  links = index_dom.css('a').each { |link|
    build = link.text
    if build.end_with?(".tar")
      builds.push(build)
    end
  }
  rc_builds = []
  builds.sort.each { |b|  rc_builds << b }
  p rc_builds
```

This need to be changed to get Build name and Last modified, and output    rc_builds array sorted in ascending order by the Last modified.

No changes to index.html can be made. So solution should be based on the index.html page in example.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to access Last Modified text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I would do it:

```
dom = Nokogiri::HTML.parse index_html

builds =[]

pre =  dom.css('pre')
build_info = pre[1].text

result = []

build_info.split("\n").each do |line|
  next unless line =~ /BUILD/
  arr = line.split(/\s+/)
  result.push({
    build: arr[0],
    modified: "#{arr[1]} #{arr[2]}",
    size: "#{arr[3]}",
    size_unit: "#{arr[4]}"
  })
end


p result

#[{:build=>"BUILD.10.tar", :modified=>"27-Sep-2017 15:46", :size=>"250", :size_unit=>"bytes"}, {:build=>"BUILD.13.tar", :modified=>"28-Sep-2017 12:14", :size=>"254", :size_unit=>"bytes"}, {:build=>"BUILD.15.tar", :modified=>"29-Sep-2017 08:56", :size=>"257", :size_unit=>"bytes"}, {:build=>"BUILD.16.tar", :modified=>"29-Sep-2017 08:56", :size=>"258", :size_unit=>"bytes"}, {:build=>"BUILD.17.tar", :modified=>"29-Sep-2017 08:56", :size=>"256", :size_unit=>"bytes"}, {:build=>"BUILD.9.tar", :modified=>"27-Sep-2017 15:44", :size=>"247", :size_unit=>"bytes"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, have added sorting and everythjing work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could try by getting the `anchor`s  tags and the text by its side.

```
index_dom = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

# Access the pre tags within the parsed html
builds = index_dom.css('pre').flat_map do |link|
  # Scan for looking the modified at dates 
  text = link.text.scan(/\d+-\w+-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}/) # I'm not regex expert, I'm sure this could be better
  # Get all the anchors within the current pre tag
  link.css('a').map.with_index do |anchor, index|
    href = anchor['href']
    # Select the text by the anchor's side if this ends in 'tar'
    [text[index - 1], href] if href.end_with?('.tar')
  end.compact
  # Compact for removing nil due to the interaction with the first pre tag
end

# Sorts the array of arrays by its first value, that's the date
p builds.sort_by(&:first)
# => [["27-Sep-2017 15:46", "BUILD.10.tar"], ["28-Sep-2017 12:14", "BUILD.13.tar"]]
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, This works for me but still Tiago's answer more suitable for me.